# I Want to Print Only Last Price Of ETHUSDT

Tags: python-3.x

```
base_url = 'https://api.coinex.com/v1'
path = '/market/ticker'
par = {'market': 'ETHUSDT'}
r = requests.get(base_url + path, params=par)
print(r.text)
```

MY output is:
{"code": 0, "data": {"date": 1700561797647, "ticker": {"vol": "2206.55983980", "low": "1993.72",      "open": "2036.04", "high": "2065.50", "last": "2008.70", "buy": "2009.13", "buy_amount": "1.61535746", "sell": "2009.14", "sell_amount": "0.59906000"}}, "message": "OK"}

i want to print >>> last:2008.70

Comment: `r.text` will give you plain text, use `r.json()` and you'll get a dictionary.

Comment: i also tried r.json()['last'] its gives key error

Comment: Format the json you posted correctly and follow the correct path to your data

Comment: last isn't a value that belongs to your base response, but something on the ticker

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests

base_url = "https://api.coinex.com/v1"
path = "/market/ticker"
par = {"market": "ETHUSDT"}

data = requests.get(base_url + path, params=par).json()
last = data["data"]["ticker"]["last"]
print(f"{last=}")
```

Prints:

```
last='1965.74'
```